# How to calculate infrastructure cost of Hbase

Tags: hbase, amazon-emr, large-data, software-design

I am trying to compute the cost of the Hbase infrastructure using AWS EMR, but not able to find documentation for costing HBase read/storage/write.
Can I get some pointer/help around it?

Answer (score 0):

AWS EMR pricing information is available [here](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/pricing/?nc=sn&loc=4). If you share more details, happy to try to help but I believe AWS EMR just charges for the use of the underlying instances.

If you have existing resources you can also sign up for [Vantage](https://vantage.sh) for free and they'll tell you what your current costs are.

Comment: Hi,@ben-schaechter, I will need to store 24 TB of data, 1000queries per day over it. A query can return data of size in 10s of GB. What will be cost of it as I am not able to figure out from  AWS docs

Comment: @Darshan Amazon EMR pricing is based off of the underlying compute. The storage costs would be an equivalent EBS Volume so I'd encourage you to look at accompanying EBS rates for the region you're planning on deploying in. 1000 queries per day is hard to give an estimate on as well as you're billed for the instance and theoretically all of those instances could handle 1000 queries per day.